# Question on maximal value of $f(0.4 + 0.5i)$ subject to certain constraints. Use of maximum principle?

Tags: complex-analysis, maximum-principle

> The function $f(z)$ is analytic in the unit disk $U = {z:|z|<1}$ and continuous in the closed unit disk. Suppose that $\frac{f(z)}{z^2}$ can be extended to be analytic in the (open) unit disk U (also at the origin). If $|f(z)| \leq 6$ in the closed unit disk , what is the maximal possible value for $f(0.4 + 0.5i)$ ?

I guess I should somehow be using the maximum modulus principle or the Cauchy estimates, but I'm not sure how.  Grateful for any help with this!

Comment: Is there a typo with the arguments for $f$? It currently has 3 arguments.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean...

Comment: What complex number are you plugging into $f$? Currently, your input is the tuple $(0,4+0,5i)$.

Comment: Well, I want to plug in the complex number 0.4 + 0.5i.

Comment: Sorry, in Finland we use , instead of .
Any thoughts on the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should apply the maximum principle to the function $g(z) = f(z)/z^2$.  Since $|g|\le 6$ on the boundary, $|g(0.4+0.5i)|\le 6$. Put this back in terms of $f$ to get the desired upper bound.

To demonstrate its sharpness, arrange $f$ so that $g(z)\equiv 6$.

Comment: Okey, is $|g| \leq 6$ on the boundary because by maximum principle $f(z)$ (and $g(z)$) takes its maximum value on the boundary and $|g(z)| = |\frac {f(z)}{z^2}| = \frac {|f(z)|}{|z|^2} \leq \frac {6}{1^2} = 6$?

I get: $|g(0.4 + 0.5i)| \leq 6 \rightarrow \frac {|f(0.4 + 0.5i)|}{|z|^2} \leq 6 \rightarrow |f(0.4 + 0.5i)| \leq 6|z|^2 \rightarrow |f(0.4 + 0.5i)| \leq 6(0.4^2 + 0.5^2) = 2.46$
Is that right? Very grateful for feedback.